# OSX - Remove empty cells from NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` which I fill correctly with some content. 
The problem is that when I run the app the empty cells stays visible and squeezed to the default size.  
I'd like to get rid of them, but I cannot find a solution for OSX (a Swift solution would be appreciated)

[image]

The red colored area shows the empty cells in the UI, while the first 2 rows are filled with content.
Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }
```

Comment: Actually my `array.count` (which is mutable, hence dynamic) is 2, I mean I do not have a prefixed number of items which may or may not contain data. Sorry if I didn't paste any code, I hoped there was a solution similar to iOS where you simply need to add an empty `UIView()` as footer of the `UITableView`

Comment: I added the code I'm using to count the number of rows. I tried printing the value and it's 2 (i.e. correct). I tried to remove the row separator and the "effect" is that I have only 2 rows, since the blank ones act as a white background. Could not find anything to solve this, for the moment I'm gonna go without row separators but I don't like very much this hack :-(

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to subclass / extend the TableView and override the drawGrid method. This will work well if you have only one column, as you have asked.
But if you have multiple columns, all the vertical grid lines will be gone as well.

```
class MyTableView: NSTableView {
   override func drawGrid(inClipRect clipRect: NSRect) {
    // Do nothing.
   }    
}
```